# Why I can not get the model status via curl in tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow-serving

**First:** I startup the sample 'half_plus_two_2_versions' via tensorflow_model_server

**Second:** I use 'curl -X GET http://localhost:8501/v1/models/half_plus_two_2_versions', but I get the error message: { "error": "Malformed request: GET /v1/models/half_plus_two_2_versions" }

Who can help me, thanks.

I can use the following command get the result:
`curl -d '{"instances": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/half_plus_two_2_versions:predict`

Result:
`{ "predictions": [2.5, 3.0, 4.5 ] }`

Thanks.

I already solve this problem.